# android's substitution for geocoder

Tags: android

I'm using google geocoder service on Android to get description for my location if provided latitude and longitude. so far I've been able to obtain lat&long-itude of my current possition,but there seems to be problems using geocoder to get location name or zipcode,etc. below is my code fragment:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);
        Log.v("IGA",""+myList.size());
        Address address = (Address) myList.get(0);
        if (myList != null && myList.size() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "country: " + myList.get(0).getCountryName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

myList.size() always returns 0.I don't know if there is something wrong with my code or anything else.
with google, I get some clues , and this is what android online doc says:

*The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.* 

I don't know what this backend service is,and being worn out, desprate to wonder if any third-party web service will do the same trick.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

GeoCoder Works only on devices, but if you are not sure on tha avaiability of GeoCoder api, use google rest api as alternate to GeoCoder Api, see following link:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

to get Address by inputing latitude and longitude, it returns results in json string, if you want to get results in xml instead of json use xml in place of json in url.

Comment: really works,thought with connection times per day limitation set by google.thanks again!